# Chrome inspector failing to connect properly to cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, google-chrome-devtools

I have built a cordova web/progressive app that I deploy to various Android phones.  Until recently chrome inspector worked just fine for debugging purposes. But now I can't use my desktop keyboard to interact with the app on the phone, the buttons on the app won't respond to desktop mouse clicks (in inspector) and while the Inspector is connected to the phone/app, the phone app buttons are not responsive to touch...as best I can tell the app isn't responding to anything.

Even in the few screens I can see with Inspector, I can't "inspect" any elements that are on the Inspector screen.  Its like all Chrome Inspector can do is show the app start up (starts just fine) and see the app on webview of Inspector...but nothing else seems to be working.

When I disconnect the phone from the computer...or simply don't initiate Chrome Inspector whiles it is connected...my app works just fine.  But with Inspector, nothing seems to be working anymore.

```
Win 7, 64-bit
Chrome: Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

My app environment:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 8.0.0
Cordova-android: 7.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Version: 1.3.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v6.10.3
```